# Counting relations inside a loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a many-to-many relationship between 'forms' and 'fields', on my intermediate table I have an additional column called 'order' so that I can edit the order of fields on a form.

I have this code for adding fields to forms. It takes an array of field ids and then loops through them and attaches them to the form. But once the fields are attached, the order is 0 for both of them when I dd?

I thought on the first iteration of the foreach, order would = 0 and on the second time it would = 1?

Assuming I was adding 2 fields to a form that didn't have any fields before.

```php
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $form = Form::findOrFail($request->formId);

        foreach($request->fieldIds as $field) {
            $form->fields()->attach($field, ['order' => count($form->fields)]);
        }
        dd($form->fields()->get());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing it like this:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $form = Form::findOrFail($request->formId);

    foreach($request->fieldIds as $order=>$field) {
        $form->fields()->attach($field, ['order' => $order]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this method would work assuming I add all the fields to the form at once. However if I add another field to the form later on down the line the new field will have order 0?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more trial and error this seems to work.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $form = Form::findOrFail($request->formId);

        foreach($request->fieldIds as $field) {
            $form->fields()->attach($field, ['order' => $form->fields()->count()]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this here:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $form = Form::findOrFail($request->formId);

        foreach($request->fieldIds as $field) {
            $form->fields()->attach($field, ['order' => $form->fields()->get()->count()]);
        }
    }
```